# Externalize application.properties to docker env

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, ldap, openldap

I'm developping an application using spring-boot and Docker. For security reasons I want to not use any more application.properties and use only environnement variable.

If you have best practices I will be grateful.

This is a snipet of my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.1"
services:
app_users:
    image: images/app_users
    container_name: app_user_ctn
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "30333:8080"
    external_links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql/myDB?autoReconnect=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: mysqluser1
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: mysqlpwsword
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      LDAP_PASSWORD: ldapPswd
      LDAP_URLS: ldap://myServer:389
      LDAP_USERNAME: cn=admin,dc=com,dc=expl
```

When I make a request to ldap I get NulPointerException because ldap environnement variables are not initialize.
When I use application.yml it works.

```
...
spring:
  ldap:
      password: ldapPswd
      urls: ldap://myServer:389
      username: cn=admin,dc=com,dc=expl
 ....
```

Would you have any ideas ?

Best regards

Comment: `LDAP_PASSWORD` != `spring.ldap.password`. You should use `SPRING_LDAP_PASSWORD`.

Comment: you could use 1 env variable for spring boot defining your application properties as json and all should work out of the box

Comment: @pandaadb thanks but I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: @Victor you can read it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html `The SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON properties can be supplied on the command line with an environment variable. For example in a UN*X shell:
$ SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"foo":{"bar":"spam"}}' java -jar myapp.jar`. The way i read that is that you can define all properties in json format using the above variable and that way you don't have to specify X variables in your docker file. It is just a personal preference thing